# Where can I find Google Scanned Objects?

Tags: simulation

From [Scanned Objects by Google Research: A Dataset of 3D-Scanned Common Household Items](https://blog.research.google/2022/06/scanned-objects-by-google-research.html), it mentions google scanned objects are hosted on [Open Robotics](https://www.openrobotics.org/) but I couldn't find it.

> In “[Google Scanned Objects: A High-Quality Dataset of 3D Scanned Household Items](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.11918.pdf)”, presented at [ICRA 2022](https://www.icra2022.org/), we describe our efforts to address this need by creating the [Scanned Objects](https://app.gazebosim.org/GoogleResearch/fuel/collections/Scanned%20Objects%20by%20Google%20Research) dataset, a curated collection of over 1000 3D-scanned common household items. The Scanned Objects dataset is usable in tools that read [Simulation Description Format](http://sdformat.org/) (SDF) models, including the Gazebo and [PyBullet](https://pybullet.org/) robotics simulators. Scanned Objects is hosted on [Open Robotics](https://www.openrobotics.org/), an open-source hosting environment for models compatible with the Gazebo simulator.

Could anyone tell me how to download the 3D models from it?

Comment: You seem to have a point: This search of the openrobotics.org site for ["scanned objects"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aopenrobotics.org+%E2%80%9CScanned+Objects%22) shows nothing at all. It should be noted that the "Community Projects" link on the home page is broken, so maybe the scans were under that link (somewhere)..?

Comment: There is another link, [Google Scanned Objects](https://app.gazebosim.org/GoogleResearch/fuel/collections/Google%20Scanned%20Objects), linked to from [IBRNet](https://github.com/googleinterns/IBRNet), but this is also a 404.

Comment: There only seems to be one question being asked, which is "How can I get hold of the *Google Scanned Objects*?", or, in other words, "Where are the scanned objects?" - which both effectively ask the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the collection was renamed and broke the link @Greenonline found, but https://app.gazebosim.org/GoogleResearch is working right now (and would keep working even if the 'Scanned Objects by Google Research' collection is renamed again).

It would be helpful if on the 'Oops!' 404 page that an invalid collection name results in it showed a list of valid collections from the same organization.

[image: google scanned objects]

Comment: Oooh, I was so close! If only I had explored and shortened the URL a bit... Nice find! :-)